# Left set of keys don't work when pressed together

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I recently bought  a brand new HP keyboard, the left set of keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>) pressed with any other key (all at a time) doesn't really seem to work, while they work just fine when pressed separately. The right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys are working properly though.

I also tried uninstalling drivers and reconnecting my keyboard but still no change.

Answer (score 0):

That could be down to a faulty keyboard. Just because it is new, although it should pass quality checking at the factory, it doesn't mean it is not without faults.

Quality checking in factory will entail randomly selecting keyboards to check for quality. Yours might have been checked and got damaged in transit. It might have missed the random check and others in the batch will be fine.

Take the keyboard back to the store for a free replacement under warranty and you should find everything works.